# Can a line from a text file be accepted as several arguments in a class constructor?

Tags: java

```
public class AFLMatch
{
private AFLTeam homeTeam;
private AFLTeam awayTeam;`
private int hTeam_score;
private int aTeam_score;
private int homeGoals;
private int homeBehinds;
private int awayGoals;
private int awayBehinds;

public AFLMatch(String hTeam, String aTeam) throws IOException
{
  File homeTeam_file = new File(hTeam);
  Scanner file1 = new Scanner(homeTeam_file);
  for(int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
  {
    this.homeTeam = new AFLTeam(file1.nextLine());
  }
  file1.close();

  File awayTeam_file = new File(aTeam);
  Scanner file2 = new Scanner(awayTeam_file);
  for(int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
  {
    this.awayTeam = new AFLTeam(file2.nextLine());
  }
   file2.close();
  }
public static void main(String[] args) throws exception
 {
  AFLMatch match = new AFLMatch(MelbourneDemons.txt, WesternBulldogs.txt);
 }
}
```

**Text file format:
------------------------**

```
Melbourne Demons\n
Simon Goodwin, COACH\n
14, Michael Hibberd, FB\n
1, Steven May, FB\n
8, Jake Lever, FB\n
17, Jake Bowey, HB\n
35, Harrison Petty, HB\n
3, Christian Salem, HB\n
10, Angus Brayshaw, C\n
5, Christian Petracca, C\n
15, Ed Langdon, C\n
36, Kysaiah Pickett, HF\n
25, Tom McDonald, HF\n
4, James Harmes, HF\n
30, Alex Neal-Bullen, FF\n
50, Ben Brown, FF\n
31, Bayley Frisch, FF\n
11, Max Gawn, FOL, c\n
13, Clayton Oliver, FOL\n
7, Jack Viney, FOL\n
6, Luke Jackson, IC\n
9, Charlie Spargo, IC\n
24, Trent Rivers, IC\n
32, Tom Sparrow, IC\n
-------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, e.g. for `Player` you could split the line on `"\\s.*,\\s.*"` and feed it to ctor:

```
public Player(String... fields) {
    this.id = Integer.parseInt(fields[0]);
    this.fullName = fields[1];
    this.team = fields[2];
}
```